# How do large websites scale across continents? Clones vs Single

Tags: database, web-deployment, scaling, latency

How do large websites like Google scale across continents like Asia and Europe?

Do they have separate distinct "clones" of Google, one for Asia and one for Europe - such that an account created in North America would not show up if searched on the others respectively, or do they straight up just have one massive aggregated datacenter and magically deal with the latency somehow?

Comment: if you're interested in this topic, check this blog post about stackexchange architecture http://nickcraver.com/blog/2016/02/17/stack-overflow-the-architecture-2016-edition/   You'll see all possible problems and their solutions

Comment: @AdamSkywalker thanks, ill check it out